# Webpack Platform-Specific Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Is there a way to make Webpack include certain files only on certain platforms?
For example, I have three versions of a native binary for Windows, Linux, and macOS. I tried this:

```
if (process.platform === "darwin")
{
    dllName = require("@res/tdlib/darwin/libtdjson.dylib");
}

if (process.platform === "linux")
{
    dllName = require("@res/tdlib/linux/libtdjson.so");
}

if (process.platform === "win32")
{
    require.context("@res/tdlib/win32", false, /\.dll$/);
    dllName = require("@res/tdlib/win32/tdjson.dll");
}
```

But even though I'm building on Windows, Webpack is still including all of the binaries. Is it possible (and a good idea) to include only the binaries for the platform I'm building on?